# Does the following operator map monotonic $C^1$ functions into monotonic $C^1$ functions?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, derivatives

Here is a full context and a more detailed question.

There is an operator $T: \mathcal{C}^1[0,1] \rightarrow \mathcal{C}[0,1]$. It is defined as follows:

$$(Tf)(x) = x + (1-\epsilon) f(x) - \epsilon  x(1-x) f'(x)$$

where $\epsilon \approx 0$ is a strictly positive constant, $A \in (0,1)$.

I am interested in showing the following: 
$$ f'(x) \ge 0 \Rightarrow (Tf) \in \mathcal{C}^1.$$

If $(Tf) \in \mathcal{C}^1$, then I can argue that $(1-x)(Tf)'(x)$ goes to $0$ as $x$ goes to $1$. This was the reason why I asked the earlier question, which I think is closely related. The question is, if $f \in \mathcal{C}[0,1]$ such that $f'$ exists and is non-negative $\forall x$, then, can we argue that $\lim_{x \rightarrow 1} (1-x) f'(x) = 0$?

I have tried building counterexamples but they either involve functions like $x^2 \sin(1/x)$ which are not monotonic or, functions like, $\int_0^x e^{-1/(1-y)} dy$  which obviously go to $0$.

Comment: What is this $f''(x)$ you speak of?

Comment: If $f''(x)$ exists and I have that $(1-x)f'(x)$ goes to $0$ as $x$ goes to $1$, then can I say, $(1-x)^2 f"(x)$ goes to $0$ too?

Comment: You should then write the question that way! Don't leave your helpers guessing ...

Comment: Thanks. Changed.

Answer (score 0):

For $f'$ being continuous on the compact interval $[0,1]$, then for some $C>0$, $|f'(x)|\leq C$ for all $x\in[0,1]$. So $|(1-x)f'(x)|\leq C|1-x|\rightarrow 0$ as $x\rightarrow 1$, so by Squeeze Theorem we have $(1-x)f'(x)\rightarrow 0$ as $x\rightarrow 1$.

$f''$ need no exist, so the second question is hard to tell.

Comment: Thanks. Suppose $f'$ exists everywhere but may not be continuous. Can we still say that $(1-x)f'(x)$ goes to $0$?

Comment: No, for simplicity, let us think about $xf'(x)\rightarrow 0$ or not whenever $x\rightarrow 0$. A counterexample would be $f(0)=0$, $f(x)=x^{2}\sin(1/x^{2})$.

Comment: But $f$ isn't monotonic there. My sense is that this monotonicity should put a lot of discipline on $f$ and $f'$ too.

Comment: I have to think about that.

Comment: @Aditya  No, you can have $f$ monotonic and $f$ differentiable everywhere, while $(1-x)f'(x)$ does not go to $0.$

Comment: @zhw.Thanks. Do you have a counterexample?